# Invisible SoundCloud iframes

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, xmlhttprequest, flash, soundcloud

On pages containing multiple SoundCloud iframes, a random subset of those iframes appear invisible in both Chrome and Firefox, and instead of containing the normal SoundCloud content they contain the following HTML. The iframes affected often change with each page load, and youtube iframes on the same page are unaffected. Does anyone know the cause and/or a workaround?

UPDATE: On further examination, this *is* standard SoundCloud content, except div id="widget" is empty, and a manual iframe reload on an individual iframe forces it visible. Is this maybe a situation where the iframe is first loaded, then the div content is fetched with an XHR, and on a page where the browser is laboring over numerous loads on a congested network some XHR's silently time out? If so SoundCloud, could you increase your XHR timeout?

UPDATE 2: I tested this some more on 2 separate machines on the same LAN, and it looks like it might be a problem with the current version of the standard Flash plugin (11.5.502.110 on winXP--installed by auto-update Nov.9, about when this started, and 11.2.202 on Ubuntu 12.04--installed today, Nov. 27). The following information should make it reproducible. I get 100% consistent failures in Firefox on both machines, and I can toggle the failures on and off in Chrome (on both machines) by enabling the standard plugin vs. Chrome's own PepperFlash plugin. There are 100% no failures with PepperFlash, but the current version of the PepperFlash player is unusable because of [impossibly choppy audio](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/LdKbj-prkfc).

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <title>SoundCloud Widget</title>
        <base target="_blank">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/player/assets/widget-22748325.css">
        <script src="/player/assets/widget-ab572693.js"></script>
        <script>
            require(["lib/support", "lib/flash-widget"], function(support, flashWidget) {if (support.newWidget) { require(["application"], function(A) {A.start("207ad5d2")}) } else { $(flashWidget.start); }});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class=" hasGoogleVoiceExt">
        <div id="widget" style="height: 100%;"></div>
        <div id="sm2-container" class="high_performance swf_error" style="z-index: 10000;"><embed name="sm2movie" id="sm2movie" src="/player/assets/swf-8bc33658/soundmanager2_flash9.swf" quality="high" allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor="#ffffff" pluginspage="www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" title="JS/Flash audio component (SoundManager 2)" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" haspriority="true"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for reporting this! We'll look into it and I'll update this page with what we find. If you have a particular URL where you see this happening, it'd be very helpful.

Comment: @gryzzly: sure, [link](http://www.logosguildworksministries.org/iabrahamCo/pRisen)

Comment: Hey Peter. Could you tell me if you see similar problem appearing for example on http://blog.soundcloud.com? I am having hard time reproducing the problem in either Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @gryzzly: yes, on a typical load 8 to 10 iframes fail at blog.soundcloud.com.

Comment: @gryzzly: see UPDATE 2, above.

Comment: Hey Peter, we tested on Ubuntu on Chrome and Firefox (with these particular versions of flash plugin) and on Mac, and on Windows and we couldn't reproduce it so far, I've tried to imitate slow connection and still didn't get this behaviour. We'll keep looking at it and I'll update you if we manage to catch it. Sorry for inconvenience :(

Comment: i had this kind of problem some time ago. i found that flash block, even it was disabled for that domain, got confused and on some frames still was blocking the flash. try removing the flash block addon/extension, and you will see all the iframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a look at this again after giving Adobe a couple of months to get their act together, and the problem is now gone in Chrome and Firefox on XP with version 11.5.502.149 of the Flash player. I haven't checked Ubuntu, but presumably they pushed the change out there too.